# Search SQL Server table for a hexadecimal range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table of hexadecimal values stored in a `varchar(32)` column. The values can be anywhere between `000FFF100000` and `000FFFA90FFF`

I would like to find all rows between `000FFF300000` and `000FFF7FFF05`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you can't do the sensible thing and change the datatype of the column to be `VARBINARY(10)`, then just convert the value in the `VARCHAR` column into `VARBINARY(10)` and then test to see if it is in that range. For example:

```
SELECT tmp.*
FROM   (VALUES ('000FFF5060B0'), ('000FFFD00DEE')) tmp(col)
WHERE  CONVERT(VARBINARY(10), tmp.[col], 2) BETWEEN 0x000FFF300000 AND 0x000FFF7FFF05;
```

returns only the following row:

```
000FFF5060B0
```

The style number of "2" in the `CONVERT` function allows a string of hex bytes *without the preceding "0x"* to be converted into binary without assuming that the hex bytes are encoded characters.

**IF** you will be doing such queries frequently, then it would be best to do the following:

1. Create a *non*-persisted Computed Column for that expression (i.e. `ALTER TABLE {schema_name}.{table_name} ADD {column_name} AS (CONVERT(VARBINARY(10), [{varchar_column_name}], 2));` )
2. Create a non-clustered Index on that non-persisted computed column

Comment: Why not just `SELECT tmp.*
FROM   (VALUES ('000FFF5060B0'), ('000FFFD00DEE')) tmp(col)
WHERE  tmp.[col] BETWEEN '000FFF300000' AND '000FFF7FFF05'`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Hi there. The initial reason is that I didn't think of it ;-). However, while it does seem to work, and probably would in many / most cases, I am pretty sure that it is more scalable to compare the VARBINARY than the string form that would likely be a case-insensitive Collation, unless the O.P. could guarantee that the data was in all upper- or lower- case. If there was guaranteed standardized casing then a binary Collation would work. But still, I tend to prefer that, ideally, a thing should be what it is intended to be: if this is binary data, then it should be treated as such.